# Как закрыть процесс, созданный функцией CreateProcess не используя TerminateProcess?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

Возник вопрос, как закрыть дочерний процесс который создаётся функцией CreateProcess() без использования Terminate Process?
Вот часть кода программы по созданию процесса. Знаю, что можно использоваться CloseHandle, но не совсем понимаю как это реализовать, если, например, открыто несколько дочерних процессов.
Процесс создается при нажатии на кнопку `void MainWindow::on_b2_clicked()`, и закрываться он должен тоже при нажатии на другую кнопку `void MainWindow::on_b3_clicked()`.

```
void MainWindow::on_b2_clicked()
{
    STARTUPINFO si = STARTUPINFO();
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = PROCESS_INFORMATION ();
    CreateProcess(L"C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    
}
```

Comment: `CloseHandle` закроет хендл процесса, но не сам процесс. Копать надо в сторону посылки `WM_CLOSE` окну процесса, но для этого надо как-то найти хендл этого окна.

Comment: Почему бы не использовать QProcess вместо CreateProcess?